# How to make bootstrap sub dropdowns popup at right side in a parent grid dropdown?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, dropdown

Can you please help me with this plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/ZDVUBAxMEFnoGV6GfL88?p=info

> Not sure why plunker preview view not showing things. Please open a new
>   window by clicking right top button in preview view, which should show
>   something.

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header" class="sticky shadow-after-3 clearfix">
    <header id="topNav">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-collapse pull-left nav-main-collapse collapse submenu-dark">
          <nav class="nav-main">
            <ul id="topMain" class="nav nav-pills nav-main">
              <li class="dropdown mega-menu">
                <!-- PORTFOLIO -->
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
                    PORTFOLIO
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-5th">
                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                          <li>
                            <span>GRID</span>
                          </li>
                          <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">1 COLUMN</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                              <li><a href="#">SUB COLUMN 0</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">SUB COLUMN 1</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">SUB COLUMN 2</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">SUB COLUMN 3</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">SUB COLUMN 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <a href="#">2 COLUMNS</a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <a href="#">3 COLUMNS</a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <a href="#">4 COLUMNS</a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <a href="#">5 COLUMNS</a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <a href="#">6 COLUMNS</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
```

Mouse hover at GRID > 1 COLUMN, the sub column will pop up below. But this is not as expected. I expect the sub column to appear at right side of '1 COLUMN'. Please see the attached mock up for the expected behaviour. Not sure how to achieve that, please help, thanks!

[image: Expected behaviour]

Comment: your plnkr not showing anything, please check?

Comment: @kukkuz please launch the preview in a new window, which should work.